# Converting Mysql to No sql databases

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I have a production database server running on MYSQL 5.1, now we need to build a app for reporting which will fetch the data from the production database server, since reporting queries through entire database may slow down, hence planning to switch to nosql. The whole system is running aws stack planning to use DynamoDb. Kindly suggest me the ways to sync data from the production nosql server to nosql database server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remember the simple fact that any NoSQL database is essentially a document database; it's really difficult to automatically convert a typical relational database in MySQL to a good document design.

In NoSQL you have a single collection of documents, and each document will probably contain data that would be in related rows in multiple tables.  The advantage of a NoSQL redesign is that most data access is simpler and faster without requiring you to write complex join statements.

If you **automatically convert** each MySQL table to a corresponding NoSQL collection, you really won't be taking advantage of a NoSQL DB.  This is because you'll end up loading many more documents, and thus make many more calls to the database than needed and thus loosing simplicity and speediness of NoSQL DB.

Perhaps a better approach is to look at how your applications use the MySQL database and go from there. You might then **consider writing a simple utility script** knowing fully well your MySQL database design.

Answer (score 4):

As the data from a NoSQL database like MongoDB, RIAK or CouchDB has a very different structure than a relational database like MySQL the only way to migrate/synchronise the data would be to actually write a job which would write the data from MySQL to the NoSQL database using SELECT queries as stated on the MongoDB website:

> Migrate the data from the database to MongoDB, probably simply by writing a bunch of SELECT * FROM statements against the database and then loading the data into your MongoDB model using the language of your choice.

Depending of the quantity of your data this could take awhile to process.

If you have any other questions don't hesitateo to ask.